# JS File using laravel inertia.js with vue.js3 template not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm new to inertia.js

My CSS file is working, my JavaScript file is not.
I am using inertia.js with Laravel 9 with vue.js-3

Using admin HTML template I'm bulding an admin dashboard but I'm facing a problem that my JS file was not working but when I used normal Laravel 9 with blade.php concept it worked perfectly.

So I tried for 2 days with different paid admin templates but it was not working.

I tried the methods below but it is not working:

My code:

APP.BLADE.PHP FILE

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
<!-- //css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dashlite.css?ver=3.1.1">
    <link id="skin-default" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css?ver=3.1.1">
     
<!-- //js -->
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/js/jsvectormap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/world-merc.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/us-merc-en.js')}}"></script>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried this method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dashlite.css?ver=3.1.1">
<link id="skin-default" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css?ver=3.1.1">
```

```
<script src="assets/libs/jsvectormap/js/jsvectormap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/world-merc.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/us-merc-en.js"></script>
```

Method 2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dashlite.css?ver=3.1.1">
<link id="skin-default" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css?ver=3.1.1">
```

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/js/jsvectormap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/world-merc.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/us-merc-en.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution to this, so rather than adding the js and css in the app.blade.php file, move asset folder resources folder.

Import the all css file in **app.css** like as

```
//resources/css/app.css
@import '../assets/css/dashlite.css?ver=3.1.1';
@import '../assets/css/theme.css?ver=3.1.1';
```

same import the all js file in **app.js** like as

```
//resources/js/app.js
import("../assets/libs/jsvectormap/js/jsvectormap.min.js");
import("../assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/world-merc.js");
import("../assets/libs/jsvectormap/maps/world-merc.js");
```

Now in **app.blade.php** add css and js inside the vite directive

```
 @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css', 
 "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
```

May this will help you. Happy coding

Comment: Not working and im not getting any error but getting whit plan page

Comment: can you check my code by anydesk remote

Answer (score 0):

Try Vuejs themes. I was having same problem, but I changed to Vueja themes, try admin one inertia theme

Answer (score 0):

Modify your app.blade.php as shown below;

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js/app.js'])
```

Note that in my case, I have stored my js file in the path /public/assets/js/app.js